# KivyMD MDTimePicker is not returning time, MDTimePicker returns None

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make a program where the program makes the user pick a due date and time for their tasks. User presses a button to open a dialog that takes task name, description and due date-time from them. Everything is fine, except I couldn't make the get_time() function do anything other than return time. And it returns None instead of the picked time. I made a seperate test app just to test if the picker works and it does. It can change the text of a label too, not just return time.

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker, MDTimePicker
from datetime import datetime
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    task_list_dialog = None
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    
    def show_task_dialog(self):
        if not self.task_list_dialog:
            self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create Task",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContent(),
            )
            
        self.task_list_dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()
    
    def add_task(self, task, description, task_date):
        self.root.get_screen("testwin").ids['container'].add_widget(ListItem(text="[size=18]"+task.text+"[/size]", secondary_text=task_date))
        print(task.text+"\n", description.text+"\n", task_date)
        task.text = '' # set the dialog entry to an empty string(clear the text entry)
        description.text = ''


class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M'))

    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save)
        date_dialog.open()

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        date = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        time = self.show_time_picker()
        
        self.ids.date_text.text = date+str(time)

    def show_time_picker(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog.bind(time=self.get_time)
        time_dialog.open()
    
    def get_time(self, instance, time):
        return time


class ListItem(TwoLineListItem):
    def __init__(self, pk=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pk = pk
 

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestWindow(Screen):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: include testwindow.kv

WindowManager:
    TestWindow:
```

testwindow.kv

```
<TestWindow>:
    name: "testwin"
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'    
                ScrollView:
                    do_scroll_x: False
                    do_scroll_y: True
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                    size_hint: 1, 0.7

                    MDList:
                        id: container
                    
                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    icon: 'plus-thick'
                    on_release: app.show_task_dialog()
                    elevation_normal: 10
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0.82, 'y': 0.07}


<DialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "420dp"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Task"
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text, task_desc, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())

        MDTextField:
            id: task_desc
            mode: "fill"
            multiline: True
            hint_text: "Task Description"
            size_hint_y: 0.1

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'calendar'
            on_release: root.show_date_picker()
            padding: '10dp'

        MDLabel:
            spacing: '10dp'
            font_size: 15
            id: date_text
        
        
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: 0.1

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: savetask
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.add_task(task_text, task_desc, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            id: canceltask
            text: 'CANCEL'
            on_release: app.close_dialog()


<ListItem>:
    id: the_list_item
    markup: True
    multiline: True
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder I have to look at the code again and the code is in my other device which I don't have with me right now. I'm sorry, I can only post it tomorrow. And thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in method `on_save` you assigned the returned value of the method `show_time_picker` (which is clearly `None`) to a var. `time`. That's why you never get the time value (instead of that None).

One of many ways to achieve that is as follows:

First create class attributes to store the desired values. This way you will be able to separate attrs. from methods and access those attrs. anywhere in your code.

```py
class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Create new attributes to save desired data later.
        self._time = None
        self._data = None
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M'))

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        # Assign the date value hare.
        self._date = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        # Open time picker.
        self.show_time_picker()


    def show_time_picker(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
#        time_dialog.bind(time=self.get_time)
        time_dialog.bind(on_save=self.get_time)
        time_dialog.open()

    # Here's a conventional trick for checking what 'args' or 'kwargs' are used by some method.
    # For that, define that function with variable no. of args and kwargs and print those.
    # def get_time(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print(args, kwargs)
        # As you see that should be two args, 'MDTimePicker' object and the 'time' value but with no kwargs.
        # So you can write it as,
    def get_time(self, instance, time):
        # Assign the time value here.
        self._time = time
        # Now set date and time.
        self.ids.date_text.text = self._date+str(self._time)
```

---

### Note:

Since in method `show_time_picker` you [**`bind`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=property%20observer#observe-property-changes) a kivy property `time` (of `MDTimePicker`) to a method (`get_time`), so this method (`get_time`) will only be called whenever the value (`time`) changes. In simple words, say, the user just opens and then closes the time-picker without modifying the time, then as the value has not changed, the default value (`None`) will be used.

That's why it is safe to use (by forcing the user to use ok button) another default method `on_save`.

Comment: This code worked on the test application. I know that if I write comments that are just me thanking, they'll probably get deleted. So I wanted you to know that I really appreciate your help. Now here's the thing. I don't know why but get_time function doesn't work at all in the actual program. I can't think of anything that can prevent that function from working. I put print("hello") in both get_time functions and test app printed but normal app didn't print.

Comment: Remember that method `get_time` is bounded to `time` which means it will respond ONLY when the prop. `time` changes (i.e. you select different values from the default ones). In any other cases you should try using method `on_save` of `TimePicker`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. Should I bind on_save function to both date and time pickers? I'm also sorry for replying late. Between my driving licence course stuff I forgot.

Comment: Also, I'm using locale module in the app to change date and time to Turkish. Can that have an unwanted effect? (I can't edit my other comment. That's why I made a second one.)

Comment: I don't think that will make any issue. However I updated the answer to clarify your first query.

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention that I knew time wouldn't change if I left it at the default value. I always change it when testing time picker. I tried to use on_save with time picker a few times but I couldn't understand how to do it. I couldn't find any examples of time picker with .bind(on_save) instead of .bind(time). Official documentation just mentions on_save as "Events called when the “OK” dialog box button is clicked." and doesn't give any examples. Google even tries to correct "time picker" to "date picker" when I write it with on_save. Are you sure I can use on_save with time picker?

Comment: If an API described about a method as fully functional then it is supposed to be so unless that the API is broken, bugged, incomplete etc. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but if I do it like that, 'self._time' stays None.

Comment: As this thread is getting longer, let me sum this up as: both the implementations I described worked as expected in my case. Make sure you didn't have any other issues in your original code.